# "Tricking" browser into loading without display in Raspbian

Tags: linux, firefox, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a headless raspberry pi, which needs to access a server on boot. As it will be using WebRTC (though attached webcam & speakers), the browser that it uses will need WebRTC support, which I think narrows it down to something like chromium or iceweasel.

The device itself will not have a display, but these browsers won't launch without one. Is there a way to trick Raspbian/the browser into thinking there is a display? (I can't forward the display to another computer).